# Images fade in at the same time

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, fade, fadeout

I Currently have a script that works on the following page:

http://universitycompare.com/

It works well and does what I want, but between each transition I have the slight delay, now what I would like to do would be to have the image fade over the top of the existing one instead of fading out the original and then fading in.

I have tried moving things around multiple times and cannot seem to get this fix! I know it's a quick one and the script I have here works so well. So Would just like someone to help me fix this is issue that has been bugging me for days!

I've missed something so simple but cannot see it.. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var $backgroundimages = ['http://www.universitycompare.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/images/ads/aru/front-page-ad.jpg', 'http://www.universitycompare.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/images/ads/uniofbuckingham/front-page-ad.jpg', 'http://www.universitycompare.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/images/ads/middlesex/front-page-ad.jpg', 'http://www.universitycompare.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/images/home-page-slide.jpg', 'http://www.universitycompare.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/images/TCE-New.jpg'];
        var $backgroundcount = 0;

        function fade($ele) {
            $ele.css('background-image', 'url('+$backgroundimages[$backgroundcount]+')');
            $backgroundcount++;
            $ele.fadeIn(1000).delay(4000).fadeOut(1000, function () {
                if ($backgroundcount >= $backgroundimages.length) {
                    $backgroundcount = 0;
                };
                fade($ele);
            });
        };

        fade($('#stretchParent  .HomeImage').first());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: For reference, you really want to have `<img>` tags representing those images somewhere, so the browser will have them loaded by the time you try to fade to them.

Comment: I'd just put them in z-indexed layers and fade out the front one, and send it to the back after, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want .fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000).delay(4000) so the in/out fade happen concurrently.

Moreover, you'll need more than one element so you can display both images at once.  I would use multiple  tags positioned absolutely on top of one another.  Then rotate through them, fading one in and another out, etc.

Echo cHao's comment too - you need to pre-cache them and hopefully optimize them - they are loading really slowly for me.

Update: Here's a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/DhESu/

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.rotator').each(function(){
        console.log('start rotation');
        imgs = $(this).find('img');
        idx = 0;
        rotate = null;
        rotate = function(){
            $(imgs[idx]).fadeOut();
            idx++;
            if (idx >= imgs.length) {
                idx = 0;
            }
            console.log('show idx ' + idx);
            $(imgs[idx]).fadeIn();
            setTimeout(rotate, 2000);
        }
        setTimeout(rotate, 2000);
    });
});
```

You're welcome.

Comment: so what would you recommend? Obviously I will have to use different images, and can place them inside a div. But what is a basic script for fading images in and out? - jQuery is always a tough one for me. Any help/direction/links is appreciated as I do want to learn.